# Error using simplexml_load_file() php

Tags: php, youtube-api

I am trying to display youtube results in my PHP page.
I have used the function `simplexml_load_file()` which is supposed to return a XML object .

```
$link = "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/aliensabductedme/favorites";
$xml = simplexml_load_file($link);
```

I get a HTTP request error.
I have come to know that gdata.youtube.com does not work now.
so.. what is the alternative to it , such that i can use `simplexml_load_file()` PHP function.

Comment: If that link no longer works, then this has nothing to do with php's function.

Answer (score 0):

Youtube has changed the url for it's xml feeds... you can find the new url by viewing the source code in the playlist you want to get the url for.  Just search for "playlist_id" in the source code and find the correct id, then use the id in the format below for the $link

```
$link = "https://www.youtube.com/feeds/videos.xml?playlist_id=FLL8mk53VPSk5tKXixJq-FTA";
$xml = simplexml_load_file($link);
```

Comment: While code often speaks for itself, answers that only contain code and have no textual explanation, get flagged for the review queues. You can avoid this by adding a sentence or two of explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is still needed, but as I migrated my code from the api-v2 to api-v3, I no longer use `simplexml`.

As it is now requiring a user, key and for ease of use, I have switched to `json_decode`

example:

```
$url_link = 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet&id=[VIDEO_ID]&key=[API_KEY]';

$video = file_get_contents($url_link);
$data= json_decode($video, true);

$vid = $data['id'];
```

..........and so on.

I kind of like it better. (^-^)